# Zend Forms in Zf2, not able to retain values

Tags: php, zend-framework2, zend-form

i am using zend forms in my zf2 application which has two text boxes. Once i submit the data, i take that and i filter the data array which i use to display it on the table. Once the data is filtered and displayed on the table, the form data is reset.

Is there a way to retain the values in the form even after submission ?

Thats the code i have, on a button click i get into this page and the action is as shown below. So this Page has a table which will get populated based on the two text boxes that i have. When i click the submit button, the data in the textboxes disappear and the data gets populated in the table.

So what i want to do here is, retain the entered values in the textboxes. Can i do that ? I know HTTP is a stateless protocol. I know i can do it using front end client side technologies, just wanted to know if there is a work around to do this.

```
public function searchAction()
    {
        //search form instantiation
        $form = new SampleForm();

        // get the post request
        $request = $this->getRequest();


        //instantiation of select for querying
        $select = new Select();

        // get parameters
        $artist = $request->getPost('artist');
        $title = $request->getPost('title');

        //prepare search criteria array
        $search = array('artist' => $artist, 'title' => $title);

        //remove empty criteria from the search criteria list
        foreach ($search as $key => $value) {
            if (empty($value)) {
                unset($search[$key]);
            }
        }
        $result = $this->getAlbumTable()->fetchAll($select->where($search));

        return array(
            'albums' => $result,
            'form' => $form,
        );
    }
```

Comment: Can you show some code? It is rather difficult to understand what is going on without an example.

Comment: ->populate data you want ? If you submit, you change the page and of course reset the form.

Comment: i have edited the question with more code. Please check it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what i was doing. I just had to do this.

```
if ($request->isPost()) {
            $album = new Album();
            $form->setInputFilter($album->getInputFilter());
            $form->setData($request->getPost());

        }
```